# Smoke domain position problem in solid mode but not in render mode Blender 2.92

Tags: smoke-simulation

I have a weird problem, when I make smoke in solid mode appears in another place.

[image: Example on solid mode]

But in render mode it is in the correct place.

[image: Example on render mode]

I was searching everywhere but I did't find anything about it.

All is ok, inclusively the render, but in solid mode it is impossible to work with.

This is an example file with the issue:

[image]

Comment: your title say "moke" instead of "Smoke" -- can you edit and correct it so others can find your issue?

Comment: I downloaded your blend file and my solution seems to work. If I move the Cube object, the smoke was stuck to its old simulation.  If I use the Domain -> Cache -> Type and change to "All" the simulation cache clears, I then change it back to your setting of Replay, and the smoke is again aligned with "Cube"

Comment: I deleted my Answer as it didn't work for you, and my Answer may be keeping others from Answering, as they may think it is solved for you.